# <ul> is wider than list items

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal list with 4 list items. I want to achieve the simple task of having the `<ul>` no wider than the cumulative width of the `<li>s` Right now my `<ul>` is wider. In Firefox's code inspector it looks like:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content-container">
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
         <li>Publications</li><li>URLs</li><li>Global Folders</li><li>Private Folders</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content-container
{
    width: 65%;
    float: right;
    background-color: Red;
}

#tabs
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

#tabs ul
{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}

#tabs ul li
{
    display: inline;
    background-color: #3E93CF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    color: #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

#tabs ul li:last-child
{
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Having added display: inline-block like:

## tabs ul

{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

I now get this:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vtPD4/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser automatically adds padding to the left of the list. This creates the default space for the bullet points. You need to set padding to zero:

```
#tabs ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ul` is a block level element and will therefore take up all available space.  Try using `inline-block` instead.

```
#tabs ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dGX2/2/)

```
#tabs ul{
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Also, that Fiddle that you linked to has the same problem - what looks like, but isn't, padding on the left.